# Вопрос по nginx. Что за папка ./var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp ?

Tags: nginx, администрирование, сервер

Здравствуйте.
На выделенном веб-сервере есть такая странная директория var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp
Для чего она нужна мне не понятно?
Причем в этой папке есть подпапки /0, /1, ... /9
И в каждом подкаталоге содержаться такие каталоги /00, /01, /02, ... /99
Все эти каталоги пусты. Зачем они нужны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_temp_path

Comment: А если такой директивы proxy_temp_path в nginx.conf нет. То почему существует такое дерево. Причем команда в консоли "find . -mtime -1" выводит список этого дерева. То есть каждый день эти каталоги изменяются.
./var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp/0/45
./var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp/0/46
./var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp/0/47
./var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp/0/48
./var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp/0/49
./var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp/0/50
./var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp/0/51

Comment: потому что эта директива была указана при сборке nginx.
nginx -V

Comment: каждый день эти каталоги используются т.к. в них создаются файлы в которые сбрасываются данные при буфферизации.